# Problems trying to upload an Android application to the Play Store

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, apk, google-play-console

I've been trying to upload an Android application to the Play Store but it only returns an error message without specifying any code.

[This is the error message that the play console returns to me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2UdX.png)

The application is somewhat heavy (weighs 450mb the Android App Bundle) since it has an RA module and 3D made in Unity. When trying to upload the AAB in the play console of the application it loads normally but after a while that error returns. Could anyone help me? It only occurs to me that it could be because it is very heavy, but previously I had tried to upload an APK with another application also quite large that I could publish with an AAB and on that occasion if I returned an error code, however on this occasion I did not.

I already tried to clear the browser's cache, I checked the project packages and it still returns the same error.

Comment: Sorry! Already updated the image

Comment: Can you try running the `bundletool validate --bundle yourapp.aab` command? Where bundletool can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases) and `bundletool` is an alias for `java -jar bundletool-all.jar`

Comment: Just to say I have the same error. Tried Pierre's validation idea and no error was thrown with the .aap. Raised it with google directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Google manage your keys when using .aab uploads. This isn't obvious and I missed it, but underneath the recommended header inviting you to use Google to sign your packages, it says in easily overlooked text that this is actually necessary to use .aabs. This makes sense as Google needs to create .apks from that .aab and sign them, but if you're happy with your signing your apps as I was, you read no further than the offer and don't learn it's essential.

If you follow that header on the Console App Upload page to let Google manage your keys, you'll have a fairly straightforward walk-through of uploading your key. I used the second option of the Java tool through the command prompt and didn't encounter any problems. Then the upload works.